# Optimal number of graph vertices when conducting an experiment

Tags: graph, graph-theory, graph-visualization

I want to conduct an experiment about graph drawing algorithms and for this purpose I have to generate graphs, but I don't know what is the optimal number of graph vertices that should be generated, is it 100 or 200 vertices ? What is the best number of vertices that humans can understand and comprehend ? How can I decide that, do you have any ideas or some papers that are useful for me, I searched online  about this topic in Google scholar and many other papers search engine, but I did not find anything.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question. Size and type of graphs may depend on the research focus.

The GDToolkit (which i am not affiliated with) publishes [several graph drawing test case collections](http://www.dia.uniroma3.it/%7Egdt/gdt4/test_suite.php) from academic literature which might be a starting point.

In general graph drawing gets more interesting the higher the number of vertices is, especially if labelling comes into play.

A number of vertices up to 100 (maybe more in graphs with a structure to exploit geometrically) has the benefit that you can ask humans to layout the graph and compare their results with what the tested algos produce.

As for the maximum number of vertices that people can 'understand', there is no fixed limit - think of a 2D or 3D lattice, the number of vertices up to which humans can grasp the essence of the graph is virtually unlimited.

There is of course a lot of leeway in what you mean exactly by 'understand'. In general human respondents will be able to tell about non-trivial properties of the graph or create hypotheses on such properties if some visual pattern shows up (this might be an interesting research topic in itself [I have not checked for existing work in this domain], think of 'distorted' drawings of lattices or drawings projections of lattices in higher dimensions).